# How do I programatically disable Etags in iis 6

Tags: iis-6, metadata, static-files

I'm trying to turn Etags off on iis 6 since I'm load ballancing multiple servers, I don't want the etag to become a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont think that you actually  turn them off, but you can set the value. Go to Default Web Site properties, the HTTP Headers Tab. Then add a custom HTTP Header with the name 'Etag' and a value  of "" (two double quotes).

Then your Yslow score will improve. =)

I believe that the thing to do in your case is to set all servers in the farm to use the same Etag value. That will allow content to be identified properly across all servers in the farm.